# check if the theme is inherited from the parent site using Jquery in SHarepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, jquery, theme

Is there any way we can check which on a site whether the theme is **being inherited from the parent site** using jQuery/JavaScript

Comment: Can you try adapting an approach proposed in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/161900/50547 to query "`__InheritsThemedCssFolderUrl`" property of SPWeb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope **OP** meant following thing from site settings.

[image]

To check whether this option is checked or not, we need to make a **REST** call to the following end-point

```
/_api/Web/AllProperties
```

It will return all properties under the web. Now find the property named `OData__x005f__x005f_InheritsThemedCssFolderUrl`. If it's value is `"True"`, then the theme is being inherited from the parent.

## Sample Code

```
function isThemeBeingInheritedFromParent() {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/AllProperties",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.d.OData__x005f__x005f_InheritsThemedCssFolderUrl == "True") {
                console.log("Theme is inherited");
            } else {
                console.log("Theme is not inherited");
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Atish, Thanks for the answer.. just want to know is there a property which contains the url of the parent site from where the theme is inheriting?

Comment: Under this end-point, there is no such property. You can try `/_api/Web/ParentWeb`

Comment: **Knives in donkeys hand** My words for those who down votes without comment!!!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get the theme info of the current and the parent web and compare them. if they are the same, you could say the theme was inherited (what's the point of applying a theme to a site specifically and have it be the exact same as it's parent, right?)

So here is the setting of a theme part (with JSOM)
[Apply theme to subsite from SharePoint hosted app + javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87720/apply-theme-to-subsite-from-sharepoint-hosted-app-javascript)

More info on inheriting
[How do I Inherit the CSS Theme Color in my Sharepoint 2013 App?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58731/how-do-i-inherit-the-css-theme-color-in-my-sharepoint-2013-app)

And getting themeinfo for a site (CSOM, but should work in JSOM too)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn985872.aspx